# "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm doing SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint online migration. During migration I'm trying to do the user mapping for the account "NT Authority\Authenticated" and "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE".

From [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/nt-authorityauthenticated-users-in-sharepoint/42e7c56e-5b76-4460-811f-ff030de74184) I came to know that "NT Authority\Authenticated" can be mapped with "Everyone except external users" in SharePoint online.

Can you please tell me what should be the mapping account for "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" in SharePoint online and why?

Thanks in advance!!..

Comment: "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" is an account used to run services on Microsoft Server. From my point of view, it's not necessary to migrate or map this account. Where is this account used excactly? On site permissions, term store admin, etc.? Why is it necessary to map this account to a new one in your scenario?

Comment: During the SharePoint on-Prem site analysis I found these accounts on the SharePoint farm and I was curious if I needed to map it during migration then which account we need to specify in SharePoint Online. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE account is used as default service accounts in Windows.

Then you also could map the NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE account with "Everyone except external users" in SharePoint online.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Service Account best practices Part 1: Choosing a Service Account.](https://4sysops.com/archives/service-account-best-practices-part-1-choosing-a-service-account/)